# Terminal flashes on empty backspace with Yosemite

Tags: macos, terminal, system-settings

Since using Yosemite, I've had the annoying problem of my current Terminal window flashing when backspacing on an empty line. I know on previous versions of OS X this flashing was not default, and could be toggled in accessibility settings, but I cannot find the same setting and I'm dying to get this turned off. Any known ways to get rid of it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is called the visual bell, and by default it’s enabled when your sound is muted. To change that setting, go into Terminal > Preferences > Profiles > <*your profile*> > Advanced.

[image: screenshot of prefpane]

You can also run

```
echo $'\nset bell-style off' >> ~/.inputrc
```

to disable Readline's use of the bell (deleting on an empty line, tab-complete, etc.). You will need to restart your session for this change to take effect.

Comment: good job bro!!!